# Change of variable in integral. Why is it performed this way in the below example?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

On a book, I read, for a certain $y\in\mathbb{R}$:

> given the integral $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-y}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$,
>   performing the substitution $x=-u$ yields:
>   $$\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y}f(-u)du$$

As to the bounds of integration, substitution is ok to me. What sounds strange is the differential. That is, I would expect:$$\frac{du}{dx}=-1$$ hence $$dx=-du$$ hence, in conclusion $$\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y}-f(-u)du$$
and *not*
$$\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{y}f(-u)du$$

Could you please clarify this doubt? I'm getting crazy since I do not know if I am making some silly mistake or if I am not realizing some basic fact or if book is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-y}^\infty f(x)dx=\int_\color{blue}y^\color{red}{-\infty}-f(-x)dx\\
=\int_\color{red}{-\infty}^\color{blue}yf(-x)dx$$

Comment: So, when performing change of variable, don't bounds of integration authomatically swap? that is, passing from $(-y,\infty)$ to $(-\infty, y)$ in this order? @Martund

Comment: No, @Strictly_increasing, they don't swap automatically. They just change according to the substitution function.

Comment: In this case, $x\mapsto -x$ is the substitution function. Therefore, $-y\mapsto y$ and $\infty\mapsto-\infty$ **at their original places**.

Comment: Sorry for this question...but why does a $-$ in front of $f(-x)$ make one pass from $(y,-\infty)$ to $(-\infty, y)$? I am pretty sure it is a very basic fact but I cannot realize the reason why it holds @Martund

Comment: @Strictly_increasing, because swapping the limits of integration induces a negative sign on the integrand.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you a lot for your patience and help @Martund